# AWS-SDK setting ACL to public-read using put object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

`s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-east-1')
obj = s3.bucket("bucket-name").object("filename.json", acl:'public-read')
obj.put(body: objects.to_json)`

The above code works as expected except for the permissions. When I view them, the read permissions are set to Owner when I need them to be set to public.

Answer (score 1):

`s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-east-1')
obj = s3.bucket("bucket").object("data/filename.json")
obj.put(body: objects.to_json, acl:'public-read')`

Turns out I was calling it in the wrong location

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax problem in this code you have to use under score and not hypen for the permission. Check this code below use `public_read` instead of `public-read`

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-east-1')
obj = s3.bucket("bucket-name").object("filename.json", acl:'public_read')
obj.put(body: objects.to_json)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your proposal? - everywhere I have read shows 'public-read' as the correct format to use.